# Change TimeZone dynamically in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, timezone, laravel-5.3

In my project there is drop-down of time zones(PT,CST etc), when Admin changes the timezone from drop-down the admin panel reflects the timezone from the selected drop down.
How to change Config/app.php "timezone"( Application Timezone) according to the selected option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Laravel helper function `config` to set timezone. However, this will affects only the request you will receive.

```
config(['app.timezone' => $timezone]);
```

If your goal is to change once the timezone and run on every request then what about saving the changed timezone in DB or in a file. Then, write a query for DB or read a file in app/config.php and change the value of index timezone in a file.

For example (file example):

When you changed the timezone it saves in a file.

```
file_put_contents("path/to/file", $timezone);
```

And, in `app/config.php`

```
$timezone= file_get_contents("path/to/file");
return [
 . . .   
    'timezone' => $timezone,
 . . .
]
```

Comment: Whenever there is change in config file, need to run php artisan config:cache to get the changes.
How the changes reflect without config:cache command?

Comment: I don't think so.... did you try? but anyway you can add exec("php artisan cache:clear") that execute random time.. or just once when the file has changed. you can use also filemtime() function. something like this now()-filemtime() < 5, then run exec command

Answer (score 19):

you need also call  [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
    config(['app.timezone' => $timezone]);
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
```

Comment: You may want to add `\Log::setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));` to the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider` to ensure the your logs are still in UTC time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep a new time zone for all future requests, you need to use a package like [larapack/config-writer](https://github.com/larapack/config-writer) to be able to save the time zone to the `app` config file.

Another way to handle this is to keep time zone in DB, fetch it in every request and set it with `config(['app.timezone' => $timezone])` dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `middleware` to achieve this, whichever routes you will write mention all those applying with that middleware.
You can fetch that data from database and apply it like as follows,

```
config('app.timezone', 'your selected timezone')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use service provider.
That way, you first need to get the settings information from the database and then change the settings inside the config file.

```
Config::set('app.timezone', $db['timezone'] ?? config('app.timezone'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In AppServiceProvider boot()

```
$settings = Settings::first();
date_default_timezone_set($settings->timezone ? $settings->timezone : config('app.timezone'));
```

This overrides default TZ value in app.php